# Php - allow only one product category in cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have two product categories

- **Package 1:** Individual software package (eg. software 1, software 2). In WooCommerce, these are added as product variations.
- **Package 2:** Bundle package (this sells all software ie. software 1 + software 2 etc)

Is it possible to configure WooCommerce such that it allows users to add multiple items in Package 1. However, there should be a restriction to cart such that at all times only products from one of the package should be in the cart and if products from another package is added, then the existing cart should be emptied.

The rationale is that:
- if a user already purchased software 2 (from package 1) and they then add package 2, it makes little sense to have them both in the cart since package 2, which includes all software, already contains software 2.

Thank you